# What word is used to describe the movements of objects caused by Earthquake?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

For example, there's a classroom and students notice the earthquake.

1. The objects in the classroom will definitely ___________ because of this.
2. The lecture stand ________ because of earthquake.

What word(s) should I use?

What I have found so far are: vibrate, shake, shiver

Comment: What isn't satisfactory about the three words you've listed?

Comment: I don't know if they are correct or incorrect.

Comment: 'Shake/Shakes/Shook' is the right choice. The others may apply under certain circumstances but in general imply a much smaller amplitude than is typically imagined for an eathequake.

Comment: Ok. Is the following sentence correct: " They cried together, "It's (an) earthquake!", as they felt some movements in objects in/of the classroom."?

Comment: "... as they felt the movement of the objects in the classroom", "...as the objects shook around them", "...as they felt the shaking of the classroom around them"...

Comment: KillingTime's answer was also equally good.

Comment: But he didn't reply to my comment.

Comment: Is it okay to use "shook" without Subject?

Comment: It would be a good idea to post these kinds of question over at ELL as all your questions are off-topic here. I was just giving a quick answer. Please ask further questions on http://ell.stackexchange.com, but it would also be a good idea to ensure you research your questions thoroughly before asking.

Comment: I didn't know aobut ELL. Can I ask such questions there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three already listed are fine, also you could try

**Tremor**, **Tremble**  or **shudder** - all of which mean to shake involuntarily

Comment: Ok. Is the following sentence correct: " They cried together, "It's (an) earthquake!", as they felt some movements in objects in/of the classroom."?

Comment: It would seem a little odd for them to 'feel' movements of objects in the room unless they are in direct contact with those objects. You could say something along the lines of "...they felt their chairs tremor and saw objects around the room shake and shudder..."

Comment: One more doubt: Chairs or desks?

Comment: Both chairs and desks would move, they're more likely to be in direct contact with their chairs so would be more likely to feel that movement.

Comment: Ok. Another doubt. Mills suggested me to use "Shake" and "Shook". Can we use this verb without Subject? For example, is this sentence correct? : They felt their chairs shake and saw movement of the objects in the classroom. (I mean it is not mentioned who shook the chairs)

Comment: Yes, that's fine because the shaking is implied to be caused by the earthquake.

Comment: In a good dictionary it will say *shake* verb **vb** transitive **trans** (we shook hands, the quake shook the building) and /or intransitive **intr** (aspen leaf shakes, the building shook, the chairs are shaking)  [ **Subject** is a different topic ]

Answer (score 1):

**Swing** (or shake) may fit:

> An earthquake of magnitude 2 corresponds to "vibrations felt by a few
> people on upper floors of buildings and in position to observe *the
> swinging* of suspended objects".
>
> From magnitude 2 to 4, *shaking* of indoor objects can be noticeable.

For your second sentence ("the lecture stand"), you may use **oscillate** or **vacillate**.

> Definition : to cause to move to and fro, to vibrate without falling